# If then esle PHP script to check database access for Wordpress

Tags: php, html, wordpress

We've had a lot of problems recently with mysql being down at our hosting company which causes our Wordpress site to display `Unable to connect to Database` instead of the Wordpress site.  I would like to add some code into the `index.php` script that checks the status of the database connection and if it fails, the load a simple html file.  Otherwise, it the database connection is good, the `index.php` script continues as normal to load Wordpress.  Below is the current index.php script for Wordpress.

```
<?php
/**
 * Front to the WordPress application. This file doesn't do anything, but loads
 * wp-blog-header.php which does and tells WordPress to load the theme.
 *
 * @package WordPress
 */

/**
 * Tells WordPress to load the WordPress theme and output it.
 *
 * @var bool
 */
define('WP_USE_THEMES', true);

/** Loads the WordPress Environment and Template */
require( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/wp-blog-header.php' );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can customize the error message when there is no database connection available.

Just create a file with the filename `WP_CONTENT_DIR . '/db-error.php'`. This will be `require_once()`ed once the connection is not successful.

If the file doesn't exist, the builtin error message is displayed.

Reference to source code: https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-includes/wp-db.php#L1652

Comment: Yup, this is the correct way to go. You can style it nicely to match your site too.